# SQL IF statements in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, if-statement

Pseudo SQL ahead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE(if var1=a then var2 must=b) 
AND (if var2=c then var3 must=d);
```

The query would return both rows with var1=a and var2=b that match the conditions, as well as all rows where var1 != a and where var2 != c.

Without using IF, using OR would ignore one of the conditions, and using AND would enforce all the conditions on each row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with boolean logic:

```
WHERE (var1 <> a or var2 = b) and
      (var2 <> c or var3 = d);
```

It might take a moment to think about why this is equivalent, but this is logically equivalent (assuming the values are not `NULL`).

Comment: Using this in conjunction with XOR solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> with var1=a and var2=b that match the conditions, as well as all rows
>   where var1 != a and where var2 != c.

the statement itself is similar to solution, if you convert it by replacing "As well as" with `OR` condition.

```
Where (var1=a and var2=b) 
OR (var1 <> a and var2 <> c)
```